# Problems with messages from different users being on the same side

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm building an app where there are two types of users: passengers and drivers. I am adding a chat interface to the app. The users are sending and receiving the messages. However, they appear on the same side, and the username is not displaying above the message. I need the sender's messages to be on the left side while the received messages are on the right side. I've looked at a lot of tutorials for chat apps, but I can't find one that will fix my problem. I used the following tutorial to get where I am now: https://github.com/mehulmpt/ionic-firebase-chat

[Chat Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHBit.png)

Here is my source code:

*I deleted some of my source code to hopefully be more concise. I've included all the code where I believe that the error could be*

```js
export class ChatPage {
  
  //creates string variables where navParam values can be stored.
  username: string="";
  rideID: string="";
  message: string="";
  _chatSubscription;
  messages: object[]=[];

  constructor(navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    //navParams values from previous page is stored
    this.username = this.navParams.get('username');
    this.rideID = this.navParams.get('requestID');
    
    //references database and creates a new child where messages can be stored
    this._chatSubscription = firebase.database().ref().child(`Rides/${this.rideID}/Messages`).on('value', snapshot => {
      let tmp = [];
      snapshot.forEach( data => {
        tmp.push({
      key: data.key,
      name: data.val().username,
          message: data.val().message,
          sendDate: Date()
        });
        return false;
       });
       this.messages = tmp;
       console.log(this.messages);
    });
  }

  send(){
    //sends the messages to the child Messages
    firebase.database().ref().child(`Rides/${this.rideID}/Messages`).push().set({
      username: this.username,
      message: this.message,
      sendDate: Date()
    }).then(()=>{
      //message is sent
    }).catch(() => {
      //some error message
    })
    
    this.message = '';
   }
```

```css
page-chat {
 .innerMessage {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: color($colors, 'primary');
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
 }
 .innerMessage.messageRight {
  background: color($colors, 'secondary');
 }
 .username {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 80%;
 }
 .message {
  font-size: 120%;
 }
 .message:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
 }
 .messageLeft {
  float: left;
 }
 .messageRight {
  float: right;
 }

 .message.special .innerMessage .messageContent{
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
 }

 .message.special .innerMessage:before{
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
 }

 .message.special .innerMessage{
  background: transparent;
  color: black;
  font-size: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
 }
}
```

```html
<ion-content padding>
 <div id="chatMessages">
  <div *ngFor="let message of messages" [class]="message.specialMessage ? 'message special' : 'message'">
    <div [class]="message.username == username ? 'innerMessage messageRight' : 'innerMessage messageLeft'">
      <div class="username">{{ message.username }}</div>
      <div class="messageContent">{{ message.message }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of just copy/pasting your whole project.  You need to define the problem and demonstrate it concisely (I need this text above this box on this side of this div).

Comment: I've edited the code to where I think the problem could be, but, like I said, I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if a the class attribute can be bound to a ternary operator. You could try something like this inside your ngFor loop

```
    <div *ngFor="let message of messages">
      <ng-container *ngIf='message.username == username'>  //Checking true
         <div class='innerMessage messageRight'>
           <div class="username">{{ message.username }}</div>
           <div class="messageContent">{{ message.message }}</div>
         </div>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container *ngIf='message.username != username'> //Checking false
         <div class='innerMessage messageLeft'>
           <div class="username">{{ message.username }}</div>
           <div class="messageContent">{{ message.message }}</div>
         </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
```